# Perl: Minus a constant (8) from 4th column of a text file

Tags: perl

My code works, except it prints some garbage at the beginning of the output file.  I can just delete it manually, but would prefer my script to work. The input file is 19 columns of number data seperated by ", " (comma space) with titles of each column on the 0th line (which I'd like to skip, another issue).

I call my file with ./column3Minus8.pl INPUTFILE > OUTPUT.txt

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;

 while(<>) {
    my @columns = split ", ", $_;
    $columns[3] = sprintf("%.5f", $columns[3] - 8);
    print join ", ", @columns;  
 }
```

The garbage at the beginning of output.txt is

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 , , , -8.00000
 , , , -8.00000use strict;
 , , , -8.00000
 , , , -8.00000while(<>) {
 , , , -8.00000 my @columns = split ", ", $_;
 , -8.00000 $columns[3] = sprintf("%.5f", $columns[3] - 8);
 , , -8.00000   print join ", ", @columns;  
 , -8.00000}, , , -8.00000
```

EDITFIX:  I was calling the perl file twice in my command line call which was causing the garbage.  "./column3Minus8.pl column3Minus8.pl INPUTFILE > OUTPUT.txt"  Oops.  I'd still like to know how to skip the first line though.  And replace the constant.

TODO: Replace constant 8 with var.  Skip the 0th row so it does not get edited.

Comment: This works remember... so adding the command line argument would get rid of the garbage?  I thought the <> read from the command line no matter what.

Comment: That seems to get rid of the garbage.  What was the argument that I could add inside the .pl for command line args so I don't have to add the "<"?

Comment: @MarcB: You don't appear to know what you're talking about. `<>` will read from the files listed in `@ARGV`, or `STDIN` if it is empty.

Comment: yes, and that's what's happening above. it read from argv[0], which is the script itself.

Comment: @johnstamos: Please write questions so that they stand by themselves. Starting with *"I have it working"* tells me nothing about your problem, and I can make little sense of it

Comment: @Borodin edited my question - "My code works, except it prints some garbage at the beginning of the output file."  I've solved this problem now.  Only problem I have now is skipping the first line to avoid editing the column headers.

Comment: @MarcB: Please don't mislead people. Perl isn't C, and the script file is in `$0`. `$ARGV[0]` is the first command-line parameter. You can read from files specified on a command line like `./script.pl inputfile > outputfile` using `<>` without explicitly opening them.

Comment: The original question that has the script intermixed with the output might be useful to other people by itself (with an answer, of course) if re-titled.

Comment: @MarcB Not quite. From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): "The array `@ARGV` contains the command-line arguments intended for the script.  `$#ARGV` is generally the number of arguments minus one, because `$ARGV[0]` is
the first argument, not the program's command name itself.  See `$0` for the command name." The OP's latest edit shows that they were passing the script name as the first argument on the command line.

Comment: sigh... right. I'll just go slink off into the corner and brush up on my perl... it's been a long time.

Comment: @Paul: I'm struggling to understand what you mean. Are you saying that people may want to write a program that reads its own source? That is a little strange, but would be best written as `open my $me, '<', $0`

Comment: @Borodin No, I meant that the following version of this question might have been useful for future readers Q:"Why does program output include program's source code?" A:"Reading from `<>` reads all lines in all files named in `@ARGV` and you included the source file in @ARGV by typing it in twice when you ran it."  As is, this looks more like the ubiquitous do-my-work-for-me-because-I-won't-lookup-how-to-define-vars-or-if-statements type of question.

Comment: @Paul: Okay. But I am struggling to believe that typing the source file name twice is a common problem.

Comment: @johnstamos I don't mean to be mean-spirited.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The goal of this Stack Overflow involves a bit of bait-and-switch.  The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a library of the world's programming questions and answers, so that when someone has a problem, they can find good examples in that library. Often questions that don't fit this pattern tend to be mercilessly downvoted, closed down, etc... A lot of questions are borderline.  I may have even asked a few of those.... Good luck.

Comment: @Borodin Using something cryptic-looking like `<>` without knowing what it does is more of a problem.  It is also difficult to google `<>`.  I suppose one can `man perlop` but even that is assuming a lot.  Just noticed I can `man perl` but not `man perlop` on this machine I am typing on...

Comment: @Borodin Since it was a typo, it could have been closed at that point using the off-topic reason of "problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error..."

Comment: @Paul: Try `perldoc perlop`

Comment: @Borodin Needs `apt-get install perl-doc`

Comment: @Paul: Without that, `man perlop` is never going to work either. I suggest you invest a few KB of disk space on the documentation!

Comment: Looking around in `perl-doc perlop` the `<>` is used in sample code before it is defined, fairly early.  The first decent explanation is pretty late in the docs and begins "The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk or any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them... "  I suppose it really is too much to expect busy people to muck through all that.... and they shouldn't have to read some murky comparisons to get to the explanation of what it does.

Comment: `while (<>)` isn't in `perldoc perlcheat` either.  Not much about files in perlcheat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are still a few minor problems with your program. You should also have `use warnings` in place, and you should `chomp` each line in case it is the *last* column that you want to modify.

This program adds the necessary code to take the value to be subtracted from the fourth column from the command line, and to copy the first line of the file.

You should run this as

```
column3minus.pl 8 inputfile > outputfile
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $delta = shift;

print scalar <>;  # Duplicate first line

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @columns = split /,\s*/;
  $columns[3] = sprintf '%.5f', $columns[3] - $delta;
  print join(', ', @columns), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Good.  But the first line, 4th column header is still edited and printed in the output file.  Still results to -8.00000.  Do see the warning about it now though.

Comment: What is the warning that you get, please?

Comment: Argument "Header 4" isn't numeric in subtraction (-) at ./column3Minus8.pl line 24, <> line 1.

Comment: Line 24 is the sprintf line.

Comment: @johnstamos:  At a guess, you don't have the `print scalar <>` line in there.

Comment: You win all the marbles.